# C# Access functions within methods

Tags: c#, function, methods, external, streamreader

I've created a method in a class and I want to access the streamreader sr1 from another method within the same class but I can't seem to get access to the method!

```
public void showSelectedFile() 
    { 
        StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ReturnTxt));
        ReturnContenctRD = sr1.ReadToEnd();
    }
public void DisposeSR1() 
    { 

    }
```

Can anyone explain to me how to access/alter these methods from other functions?

Answer (score 3):

`sr1` is local to the `showSelectedFile()` method; it goes out of scope when the method returns.  If you want to make it visible to the other method, you have to make it a member of your class:

```
StreamReader sr1;

public void showSelectedFile() 
{ 
     sr1 = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ReturnTxt))
     ReturnContenctRD = sr1.ReadToEnd();
}

public void DisposeSR1() 
{ 

}
```

If it's just a matter of disposing it properly, wrap it in a `using` statement:

```
public void showSelectedFile() 
{ 
     using (StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ReturnTxt)))
     {
         ReturnContenctRD = sr1.ReadToEnd();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the StreamReader in a class member variable

e.g.

```
class YourClass
{
    private StreamReader _sr1;

    public void showSelectedFile() 
    { 
        _sr1 = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ReturnTxt));
        ReturnContenctRD = _sr1.ReadToEnd();
    }

    public void DisposeSR1() 
    { 
       if(_sr1 != null)
          _sr1.Dispose()
    }

}
```